# How to define a observable map as a member of a class in MobX

Tags: javascript, mobx

ALl:

Thanks for reply. First day on MobX, just wonder if I user decorator inside **ES6 class**, how can I define observable [map member](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) rather than observable [object member](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/object.html)?

```
class Store {
    @observable attr = {} // I only define an Object member but not a map member
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [**observable.map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html):

```
class Store {
    attr = observable.map({})
}
```